# File I/O slowing down my C loop

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a C program that does "stuff" in a loop, where each iteration is timed to some hertz. This loop used to be able to run at about 80k hz.

Then I added some file I/O to the loop (reading/writing to linux file descriptors) and now it seems that I can't break ~6k loops/sec. The operations themselves are very cheap, so I suspect it's some kind of kernel context switch that is causing a bunch of latency. So, two questions:

- how do I check if this is the case?
- is there anything I can do about it, apart from RT-patching my kernel?

Comment: Can you give us the simplest program you can that demonstrates the problem? (including how you did the timing)

Comment: You can't rely on the timing of an untimed loop. You need to incorporate some kind of timing hardware in it. And of course I/O will slow down any flow. there is no "cheap" file IO.

Comment: Trying 80k small file IOs per second is probably not the best way to go. Can you not print it all to buffer and flush it to disk only when the buffer gets big enough?

Alternatively you can use RAM disk.

Comment: "*some kind of kernel context switch*"? Writing to a file is a [system call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call). 6k system calls per seconds sounds not too shabby ...

Comment: Disk IO **is** slow.That's the reason why buffering and in memory file systems were invented. Is one of those two classic method relevant for your use case?

Comment: Send as a code example of your loop! I think that may be some file access might slow down your loop, but if we don't see the code ... :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing to disk, write to tmpfile(). See if performance improves. On a decent implementation, it should be held in memory until it gets insanely large.
If that fixes your problem, it's write latency that is slowing you down. If you flush the entire tmpfile out in one go, you might see some improvement. Setting the buffer to a huge value will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question because there is a pretty direct solution that involves very little code modification.

If we do tons of file descriptor read/writes that is slowing down our program, we can consider using `mmap()` to map the file descriptors directly to memory and then basically treat the file as a byte array. Just make sure to allocate enough memory to fit whatever you want to write.

Comment: *If we do tons of file descriptor read/writes that is slowing down our program, we can consider using mmap() to map the file descriptors directly to memory and then basically treat the file as a byte array. Just make sure to allocate enough memory to fit whatever you want to write.* This will **NOT** solve a problem reading data from disk - in fact, `mmap` can be quite a bit slower than a simple `read()` - setting up the virtual mappings that allow you to "treat the file as a byte array" is a *very* expensive operation.It *may* work - but only if you keep referring to data that's already read.

Comment: See [this comment from one Linus Torvalds](http://marc.info/?l=linux-kernel&m=95496636207616&w=2) (you may have heard of him...): "People love mmap() and other ways to play with the page tables to
optimize away a copy operation, and sometimes it is worth it.

HOWEVER, playing games with the virtual memory mapping is very expensive
in itself.  It has a number of quite real disadvantages that people tend
to ignore ... quite noticeable setup and teardown costs ... page faulting is expensive. That's how the mapping gets populated,
   **and it's quite slow.**"

Comment: Well the point here is to optimize the read/writes inside the loop - the setup costs outside the loop are ok.

Comment: `mmap()` mappings are created on demand when the page is accessed.  They're not created when `mmap()` is called.  So you'd have to access every page in the file for the entire mapping to be created. That's exactly the same amount of IO necessary to read the entire file in to the process's memory.  And if the file is too big to fit into memory, some of those pages will be unmapped and have to be re-read from disk. `mmap()` does not make your IO problem go away. If the file fits into memory, you can just read it directly. If it doesn't fit, `mmap()` will redo the same IO ops as reading the file.

Comment: This is all very educational - you're saying that if the file I'm reading from is not very large (which is true here), then read() is not particularily slow because the kernel will buffer the data in much the same was as mmap() would...?

Comment: If you show us some code that exhibits the problem, as requested, we can help. Most likely the solution is to read/write bigger blocks, buffering.